# Wait for a thread creation and skip threads which have finished execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 4 threads, lets say A, B, C and D.
D is dependent on all 3 threads. A, B and C.
It should only start after all 3 other threads have finished execution.

In run method of D

```
    public void run() {

            for ( final String name : nameList ) {
                final Thread thread = getThreadByName( name );
                if ( thread != null ) {
                    while ( thread.isAlive() ) {
                        thread.join();
                    }
                }

            }
       //Do something
     }
```

nameList contains names of thread A, B and C.

the get thread by name method looks like

```
public Thread getThreadByName( String threadName ) {
    for ( final Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet() ) {
        if ( t.getName().equals( threadName ) ) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In my case thread A has been executed and thread B is in progress, thread C has not been submitted yet.

When thread D is submitted it tries to get thread A by name, it returns null, then it skips it and tries to get thread B by name, it returns thread B. Thread D waits for B to complete and then checks for thread C. `getThreadByName` returns null for C because the thread for C has not been submitted yet. Thread D skips it and starts executing the further code in `//Do something`

I want thread D to wait for thread C also.
It should skip thread A because it has been finished.
Wait for thread B which it is doing.
But it should wait for thread C also.

How to do this ?

Comment: maybe `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` - I never used it... also have a look at `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` and `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`.

Comment: And for the record: the answer that I give you today ... is just a more "beginner level" extension on the answer I gave you the other day on the same question. To a certain degree, this gives the impression that your java skills are pretty limited. And if that is true, I have the feeling that you are **overburdening** yourself here. You are trying to work on advanced challenging topics; but at the same time, you fail to really understand what the code you are writing down will be doing. That is not a good match. I seriously recommend you to step back and do some learning **now**.

Comment: Otherwise *no* answer that you get here will help you. Because you will just run into the next problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **for** loop just iterates **once** over the data set. You need something differently; like this:

```
Set<String> threadsToMonitoryByName = ... 

while (! threadsToMonitoryByName.empty() ) {
  for (String threadName : threadsToMonitorByName) { 
     Thread thread = getThreadByName( threadName );
       if ( thread != null ) {
         while ( thread.isAlive() ) {
            thread.join();
            threadsToMonitorByName.remove(threadName);
         }
      }
  }
  // and probably some thread sleeping here to avoid HOT waiting
  ...
}
```

In other words: you have to keep track of those threads that were processed fine; and those that weren't ready for processing.

Notes: first of all the above is more like "pseudo code" intended to get you going. There might be various aspects that require careful checking, like:

1. Using that for loop within an enclosing while loop is just *one* way to go here. You could also just pick the first element of your string list; and just work that. Many options here!
2. I am not sure if you can iterate the entries of that Set ... while at the same time, removing elements from the Set.
3. As HRgiger is pointing out: you probably don't need that check for isAlive() before calling join()
4. And probably most problematic: your `getThreadByName()` method looks like a dirty, expensive hack. If **tracking** your threads is an important in your design, then you should create a real **design** for that. For example your threads might use a central *registry* that keeps a simple `Map<String, Thread>` for a quick, well defined lookup.

Comment: Do you need to run while loop for using join?

Comment: Well, that is his code; i tried to match up as closely as possible. But I will add that to the answer; thanks!

Comment: Is `entries()` a method in the `Set<>` interface?  It's not listed in Java 7:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html  I'd also worry about modifying the set while it's being iterated over.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you very much ... that I why I wrote pseudo code. You are fully correct, as this is a set and not a map, one just "walks" the set itself. Your second point is already addressed in my notes.

Comment: @GhostCat keeping track of the threads worked for me.
I have changed the getThreadByName() method also. Thanks :)

Comment: @chumak Glad to hear that my efforts were helpful in the end. And I know, I am repeating myself, but dont forget about using that "accept" thingy right next on the left hand side of my answers then ;-)